# How to remove a package in centos 7 safely?

Tags: centos, package-management, python

I am trying to remove python but it gives me a lot of dependencies which are used by another packages.If I remove like the command below then I may render my computer unusable or some other problem might occur.

```
sudo yum remove python
```

I am just trying to remove python 2.7 and install python3 but without messing up with my system.

Comment: Install python3 *without* removing 2.7 then. Common sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't remove the `python` from RedHat 7 without breaking lots of things.  In particular, python3 isn't 100% compatible with python2.7 and so scripts and tools may break.

If you need python3 then you could install the version from EPEL (e.g. python34-3.4.5-4.el6.x86_64.rpm) which will create `/usr/bin/python3`.  Or you can use the Software Collections (SCL), which installs under `/opt` and allows you to modify PATH as necessary.  If you have a RedHat subscription then you may have access to SCL, otherwise the CentOS project makes a version available.

But whatever you do, don't make the default `python` program anything other than the RedHat provided one, otherwise things may break.

Comment: Good answer +1. In Debian is pretty much the same scenario, package management needs python.